# Image is not rendering in the DOM while passing as props in the App.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing the image name as props in the instance of the Card component in App.js. Then I am receiving it from the Card component and render it to the DOM. But my image is not showing in the DOM. What could be the reason?

This is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Hero from "./components/Hero";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import "./images/image12.png";
import "./images/Star1.png";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      <Card
        img="image12.png"
        star="Star1.png"
        obtainedRating={5.0}
        TotalRating="6-USA"
        briefText="Life lessons with Katie Zaferes"
        price="$136"
        person="/person"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Card component

```
import React from "react";
import "../style.css";
import "../images/image12.png";
import "../images/Star1.png";
export default function Card(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="card--section">
      <img src={`../images/${props.img}`} className="card--image" alt="Katie" />

      <div className="rating">
        <img
          src={`../images/${props.star}`}
          className="star--image"
          alt="star"
        />
        <small>
          {props.obtainedRating} <span>{props.totalRating}</span>
        </small>
      </div>
      <p className="brief-text">{props.briefText}</p>
      <p className="price">
        <strong>{props.price}</strong>
        {props.person}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my Folder structure

src
-components
-Card.js
-images
-image12.png
-Star1.png
-App.js
-index.js

Comment: try to import images as `import image_name from './images/...'` and then use it as `img={image_name}` in app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not working because you need to import an image like this and then put imageName as the value of src attribute**. You can give any name you like.

```
import imageName from "../images/image12.png";

src={imageName}
```

Comment: @OliUllah you are always welcome & you can also accept my answer, so this will be helpful as well as for other developers.

Answer (score 2):

Import images like:

```
import img12 from '../images/image12.png'
import star1 from './images/Star1.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

The image path can retrieved by using the import statement

like below

```
import "./styles.css";
import clouds from "./Images/clouds.jpeg";
import CardImage from "./CardImage";

export default function App() {
  console.log("cloud path", clouds);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CardImage path={clouds} alt="clouds" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.I simply imported

```
import cardImage from "./images/image12.png"
import star from "./images/Star1.png"
```

And used them in App.js

```
<Card img={cardImage} star={star}/>
```